# How to install spark in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, server

It shows error like file size is too large, I am using through my institution Internet connection its limited access. so I need help to how could install the spark???

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit version.

Reply me even whatever mistake in my communication don't mind that...

Comment: Where you are getting error *file size is too large* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `spark` in Ubuntu 12.04 as:

```
sudo apt-get install spark
```

It is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=spark).